# nunit agent hangs even after using .NET 4.0 in config file

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

I am facing issues with nunit.

When I run unit tests and close the nunit application, the application closes with significant delay and nunit86.exe process remains in memory. I need to kill it to build the code again with changes.

I face the same issue when I run the unit test cases with ReSharper.

After searching on web, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303421/nunit-2-5-8-lots-of-nunit-agent-exe) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/602761) solution.

I made the required changes in config file and found that the application closes promptly but a pop up comes saying "Nunit agent stopped working". I had to close it each time.

It is really painful as we are also using nunit on CC.NET.

Any solution for this will be appreciated.

I have used following version's of Nunit but no success

1. NUnit 2.5.5
2. NUnit 2.5.9
3. NUnit 2.5.10
4. NUnit 2.6.2

I tried it using following version's of Nunit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across this issue with nunit 2.6 to get it to work i modified the **nunit-console.exe.config** as follows:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <!-- Comment out the next line to force use of .NET 4.0 -->
    <!-- <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> commented out as it is causes nunit to hang. -->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" /> 
</startup>
```

**note the commenting out of the v2 runtime**