# nunit-console hangs when tests are run using typemock

Tags: msbuild, nunit-console, typemock, typemock-isolator

I have a msbuild project like below, through which I am running unit tests under typemock isolation.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <NunitOutputCode>0</NunitOutputCode>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
      <UnitTestAssemblies Include="$(PathOutputAssemblies)\*.UnitTests.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>

<TypeMock.MSBuild.TypeMockStart />
    <Exec Command='"C:\program files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.8\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe" /nologo /noshadow /labels "@(UnitTestAssemblies)"  /exclude=SpecialEnvironmentNeeded,FailingToBeAddressed,NotApplicationTest,PerformanceTest'
          WorkingDirectory="%(RootDir)%(Directory)"
          ContinueOnError="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="NunitOutputCode"/>
    </Exec>
<TypeMock.MSBuild.TypeMockStop />
```

However, when I run this, the unit tests run and then the process just hangs, never returns. I see the output as below in the console when it is hung.

```
Tests run: 9, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 1.1281699 seconds
Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```

This makes me to believe my tests are running fine, but the issue might be returning the exit code. Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Desclaimer, I work at Typemock. You can run this with Typemock logs enabled. Like this: <TypeMockStart LogLevel="4" LogPath="The folder where to save the log"/> and send the logs to support@typemock.com

Comment: @Al.exe thank you. As mentioned in answer below, it turned out to be not a typemock issue.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be not a Typemock issue. It was due to Nunit agent version we were using.

We have a old v2.5.8 version of Nuget and it defaults to using .net framework 2.0. The trick was to modify the agent config file as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4303508/197868) to refer to .net framework 4.0. This resolved the issue for me.